# Regular expression which allows only + , - and . in java

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

I have this String

```
String criteria="ESS.(BVA4+BVA5)+(-(DIESE.(BVM5+BVM6)))";
```

I want to put validations on it.

1. It should only contain + - or . or all the three.
2. It should not accept other symbols like !,% etc..

How to write regular expressions for that??

Comment: @ Kazekage Gaara.. i succeeded for checking + - and . but i am not getting how to restrict other special characters..and how do i combine both of these conditions.. :(

Comment: Should it contain "ESS"? "BVA4"? "BVA5"? "DIESE"? "BVM5"? "BVM6"? Your requirements aren't adequately specified yet.

Comment: Show us examples of some valid and invalid matches.

Comment: @ EJP and @ Damian Powell
LIKE-"ESS.(BVA4+BVA5)-(BVM5+BVM6).ER5))" 
"(BVA4+BVA5).(-(DIESE.(BVM5.BVM6)))"
are correct..

but
"(BVA4%BVA5)*(-(DIESE.(BVM5+BVM6)))"
"ESS.(BVA4+BVA5)<(-(DIESE.(BVM5!BVM6)))"
are incorrect!!

Comment: @sumit Can you put those examples in your question? Because that is pretty important and helps us a lot in understanding your problem. Also, put the regexp that you came up with so far and describe, what it does and what it doesn't do yet.

Comment: @ brimborium - Thanks for your concern.My problem has solved i used solution given by Tim Pietzcker(below) and added some of my previous vaidations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of guesswork goes into this:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("[A-Z0-9().+-]*");
```

This returns `true` if the string only contains uppercase ASCII letters, ASCII digits, parentheses, plus/minus signs or dots. It includes the empty string (if you don't want that, change the `*` into a `+`).

Of course, it does nothing whatsoever to check whether (for example) the parentheses are balanced correctly (which you couldn't do in a Java regex anyway).

Comment: Tim Pietzcker Thanks ..that hepled.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `String regEx="[+|\-|.|]" ;`

Comment: There are some problems here: 1. You need to double the backslashes in a Java string. 2. You don't need pipes inside a character class - right now, literal `|` will also be matched by this regex. 3. This regex doesn't solve the OP's (badly specified) problem.